# How to set a linetype for "empty points joined by lines"?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I want to make a plot in `ggplot2` like this

[image: base]

```
x <- 1:10
y <- rnorm(10) + x
df <- data.frame(x=x,y=y)
plot(x,y)
lines(x,y,type='c')
```

I like this `type='c'` style,R help tell me

> "c" for empty points joined by lines

but how can I implement this type in `ggplot2`?

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=df,aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_line() + geom_point(shape=21,size=3)
```

[image: ggplot]

I mean, how to make a blank between the empty points and the lines? which `linetype` should I choose?

thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ggplot(data=df,aes(x=x,y=y)) + 
    geom_line() +  
    geom_point(shape=21, size=5, colour="white", fill="white") + 
    geom_point(shape=21,size=3) + 
    theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Good solution! Note that the larger `geom_point` also covers the grid lines in background, which may not be intended in all cases.